# Як правильно: "московити" чи "московіти"?

Tags: правопис

Як правильно звуться жителі Московії?

[Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%8F) вживає слово "московити", але я не можу знайти це слово в словниках. В той же час, мені здається, що правильно писати "московіти" або "московійці". По яким правилам утворюється закінчення у цьому слові?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Найсучасніший і найповніший офіційний словник, СУМ-20, [подає](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=207116&page=1676):

> МОСКОВИ́Т, а, ч., заст. Те саме, що моска́ль 2. – Ми, мені здається,
>   не гірші за інших людей, за всіх, яких бачив: татар, німців, поляків,
>   московитів (Ю. Мушкетик); Всі люблять Польщу в гонорі і в славі. **Всяк
>   московит Московію трубить.** Лиш нам чомусь відмовлено у праві свою
>   вітчизну над усе любить (Л. Костенко).

Спочатку здавалося, що це необов'язково стосується Московії, але цитата з Ліни Костенко переконала у зворотньому.

Answer (score 1):

> По яким правилам утворюється закінчення у цьому слові?

Коли поглянути на словопохоџеня і приклади з инших мов ві џерелї: [Етимологічний словник запозичених суфіксів і суфіксоїдів в українській мові](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/E_LIB/PDF/ukr0004902.pdf#page=146), то стає очевидно, шчо за ⁰ дивним, страждальним і не дуже потрібним правописним [правилом девʼятки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Ви закономірно спитаєте, а чого ж таки не *московіт*? Он навіть маємо [*мусковіт*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82) — в прикладах наводять *muscovy*, але украьинське ненаголошене *о* теж [полюбяє](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par1) ставати *у*. Бо виняткове правило має чимало винятків, на котрих теж винятки, а тут це штибу *старі засвоєні слова*:

> [Примітка 1.](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5a5prym1) У ряді слів іншомовного походження, що давно засвоєні українською мовою, після **б п в м ф г к х л н** ¹ пишеться відповідно до вимоги *и*: *бурмистер* (але *бургомістр* ²), *вимпел, єхидна, імбир, кипарис, лиман, миля, мирт, нирка, спирт, химера* та ін., а також у словах, запозичених із східних мов, переважно тюркських: *башкир, гиря, калмик, кинджал, киргиз, кисет, кишлак*.

Аби разом посмакувати, додав записки:

1. Правило відносно нове, схоже, від польського впливу і затвердили під кінць позаминулосторічя. Совіти не дуже змінили з міркувань вельми доборої маніпулятивностьи і на сьогоденя, шчо про **ґ** [забули](https://r2u.org.ua/node/244).
2. Треба продовжити: *meister – [мейстер](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50454&page=1596), [майстер](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=49249&page=1550)* (десь напевно і *мастер* гуляє).